# The SelectedValue of DropDownLists are not set correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, umbraco, selectedvalue

I'm populating an ascx Panel control with some controls programmatically from the Code behind, but I cannot figure out why the 'SelectedValue' property is not set to what I would expect.

I have this code:

```
int i = 0;
{
    var row = new Panel {ID = string.Format("row_{0}", i)};
    var ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.Items.AddRange(_templateDdl.Items.OfType<ListItem>().ToArray());
    ddl.SelectedValue = "21246";
    ddl.ID = string.Format("ddl_{0}", i);

    row.Controls.Add(ddl);
    Rows.Controls.Add(row);
}
i = 1;
{
    var row = new Panel {ID = string.Format("row_{0}", i)};
    var ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.Items.AddRange(_templateDdl.Items.OfType<ListItem>().ToArray());
    ddl.SelectedValue = "21240";
    ddl.ID = string.Format("ddl_{0}", i);

    row.Controls.Add(ddl);
    Rows.Controls.Add(row);
}
```

The issue is that even though the ID's are set correctly, the SelectedValue of the first one is always the same as the last one.

Is there any way I can monitor the controls, and make Visual Studio break in case the value is changed by some other code?

Any other suggestions are welcome :)

Should probably mention that this is being done in an Umbraco solution, in case it means anything.

Thanks

Comment: When you view the properties for your DDL does it have a default value in it?

Comment: The DDL is being created by the code. When I'm stepping through it in debug, I can verify that the SelectedValue is being set correctly. It behaves as if something else is changing the ddl after it has been added.

Comment: It appears that even though the SelectedValue property set belongs the DDL, it is in fact set on the ListItem, which in this case is being copied from a template ddl, and is thus a reference to the same array.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that even though the SelectedValue property set belongs the DDL, it is in fact set on the ListItem, which in this case is being copied from a template ddl, and is thus a reference to the same array.

I wrote this code as a solution:

```
// Pass the template DDL to this function which will create a new separate List:
private List<ListItem> GetListItems(DropDownList ddl)
{
    return (from ListItem srcItem in ddl.Items select new ListItem(srcItem.Text, srcItem.Value)).ToList();
}

// Retrieve the items from the List and assign them to the DropDownList:
ddl1.Items.AddRange(GetListItems(_templateDdl).ToArray());
```